# JSF - custom NavigationHandler outcome values invalid?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, navigation

I wrote myself a custom NavigationHandler very similar to following one but just using a stack to save the history:

http://jsfatwork.irian.at/book_de/custom_component.html#!idx:/custom_component.html:fig:backnavigationhandler-code

```
public class HistoryNavigationHandler extends NavigationHandler
{
    private final NavigationHandler navigationHandler;

    private final Stack<String> outcomes;

    public HistoryNavigationHandler(final NavigationHandler navigationHandler)
    {
        this.navigationHandler = navigationHandler;
        this.outcomes = new Stack<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleNavigation(final FacesContext context, final String fromAction, final String outcome)
    {
        if (outcome != null)
        {
            if (outcome.equals("back"))
            {
                final String lastViewId = this.outcomes.pop();

                final ViewHandler viewHandler = context.getApplication().getViewHandler();
                final UIViewRoot viewRoot = viewHandler.createView(context, lastViewId);
                context.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
                context.renderResponse();

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                this.outcomes.push(context.getViewRoot().getViewId());
            }
        }
        this.navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, fromAction, outcome);
    }
}
```

Registering this one in the faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-handler>
    package.HistoryNavigationHandler
</navigation-handler>
```

Results in following log warning and a message where a previously working link was present:

```
Warning: jsf.outcome.target.invalid.navigationhandler.type

Something like: this link is disabled because a navigation case could not be matched
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since JSF 2, the [`NavigationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html) has been replaced by [`ConfigurableNavigationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ConfigurableNavigationHandler.html). All JSF 2 specific tags/components like `<h:link>` and so on are relying on it. The `NavigationHandler` is kept for backwards compatibility.

Here's a kickoff example how to properly extend `ConfigurableNavigationHandler`:

```
public class HistoryNavigationHandler extends ConfigurableNavigationHandler {

    private NavigationHandler wrapped;

    public HistoryNavigationHandler(NavigationHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleNavigation(FacesContext context, String from, String outcome) {

        // TODO: Do your job here. 

        wrapped.handleNavigation(context, from, outcome);        
    }

    @Override
    public NavigationCase getNavigationCase(FacesContext context, String fromAction, String outcome) {
        return (wrapped instanceof ConfigurableNavigationHandler)
            ? ((ConfigurableNavigationHandler) wrapped).getNavigationCase(context, fromAction, outcome)
            : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Set<NavigationCase>> getNavigationCases() {
        return (wrapped instanceof ConfigurableNavigationHandler)
            ? ((ConfigurableNavigationHandler) wrapped).getNavigationCases()
            : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: At first great thanks :), you are helping me alot with jsf. I have a few questions: As long as the outcome 'back' popping the last view from the stack is from any action method return value it works fine. But using it with a link `<h:link outcome="back"/>` is not working. `Navigation case cannot be resolved` will be printed.

Comment: Override `getNavigationCase()` and `getNavigationCases()` accordingly so that it returns non-null for an outcome of `back`.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer, yeah thought about it first but i am not so familiar yet with the complex jsf stuff. And the next question with this problem is: How do i put the initial request url into my navigation handler stack (the user used to enter the site)? (maybe i should make new so question)

Comment: Good question. I think I'd grab it in the constructor of a session scoped bean and then let the custom navigation handler get it.

Comment: Surely it is :) I do at least not immediately see other easy ways.

Comment: Especially if `preRenderView` is not working for template master files!

Comment: This is still not sufficient enough, since the navigation handler resides in session scope as far as I know, it wont work since user can open multiple windows/tabs which all would share the same history stack. I just thought it would be a good idea since a few online resources implement something similar in their tutorials. For the few cases where I need a return button I will pass the refferer as a viewParam.

Comment: I understood that you wanted to maintain the history sessionwide, not viewwide.

Comment: Hmm, i don't know what I really wanted :D, I just wanted to have a history back functionality with url's with query parameters retrieved from the `RequestParameterMap`. The user can access the login site from any other site but the back link on that site and on successfull login the user should be redirected to the reffering site. Which makes trouble using components such as 'h:link' which would be perfect for query url's, but dont invoke the navigation handler.