# custom navigation handler - handleNavigation not invoked by h:link

Tags: jsf, navigation

The handle navigation method `handleNavigation(final FacesContext context, final String fromAction, final String outcome)` from my custom navigation handler is not invoked by my h:link component?

```
<h:link value="text" outcome="./target.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
    <f:param name="param" value="#{var.prop}"/>
</h:link>
```

Using commandbutton invokes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h:link>` doesn't send a POST request whereafter the target URL is been resolved. Instead, the `<h:link>` generates a HTML `<a>` element with the target URL already right in there in the `href` attribute which is in turn to be used to send a GET request. This URL is obtained by [`ViewHandler#getBookmarkableURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#getBookmarkableURL%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map,%20boolean%29), which in turn delegates to [`ViewHandler#getActionURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#getActionURL%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String%29).

If you're using Mojarra, you can see all the job in `OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer#renderAsActive()`.

You can easily provide a custom `ViewHandler` by extending [`ViewHandlerWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandlerWrapper.html) and registering it as `<application><view-handler>`.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for explanation, but this seems useless for my case where i want to store the navigation history and redirect to the target site using the query in the url. I don't really see any solution for this right now. You have any idea?

Comment: Either send a (non-JSF!) ajax request on click to some custom servlet, or create a custom servlet filter (or maybe a hook on `ViewHandler#createView()`) which get invoked when the GET request is fired.

Comment: I think i take a complete different approach, since more and more problems arise which all need hacky workarounds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045442/jsf-custom-navigationhandler-outcome-values-invalid/12047651#comment17656842_12047651