# Passing variable to another view: best practice

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, scope

I've got a form in a view, for example say:

**form.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Name" />
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.name}" />

        <h:outputLabel value="Age" />
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.age}"
                     converter="#{ageConverter}" />

        <h:outputLabel value="" />
        <h:commandButton action="#{bean.submit}"
                         value="Submit" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Supported by the following bean:

**Bean.java**

```
@Named
// Scope
public class Bean implements Serializable {
    @Inject private Service service;

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<Person> people;

    public void submit() {
        people= service.getPeople(name, age);
    }

    // getters & setters for name & age
    // getter for people
}
```

Resulting in a view for `people`:

**result.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.people}"
                 var="person">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            #{person.name}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Day of Birth</f:facet>
            #{person.dayOfBirth}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Now obviously the use-case is similar to:
 - Submit the form using **form.xhtml**
 - Get people from service using **Bean.java**
 - Show people using **result.xhtml**

In this example there's still a small part of the puzzle incomplete. For example the scope is decisive in whether or not there are `people` at all in the result, furthermore there's no forward (or anything similar) to the resulting page.

Now I'm not sure in what would be the best (or at least a good) way to accomplish this. Here are some ways I've been able to think of:

- Using `@ViewScoped` (JSF2.2) and implicit navigation (returning a `String` from `submit()`) to navigate to the second page. However this breaks the viewscope (anyway to accomplish this)?
- Using `@ViewScoped` and include the right file (form.xhtml or result.xhtml) based on `rendered=''` with some EL. This could be done with an Ajax-call on the submit.
- Passing the values `name` and `age` as GET-parameters on a request to result.xhtml and executing the logic on a `@PostConstruct` (though, what if the form is 'huge')? In this case `@RequestScoped` would suffice.

My question is, what would be an efficient and good (best) way to accomplish this usecase?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems JSF 2.2 hasn't just provided us with `@ViewScoped`, it also has provided us with `@FlowScoped`. For more info: [documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jsf_2_2_faces_flow). This seems to fit the requirements nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [flash scope](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/).  It survives a redirect but it's not available anymore in subsequent requests.

A solution would be to pass your `name` and `age` variables via the flash scope, and use them to render your results.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems I forgot to mention I'm using CDI. An alternative would be to use Conversation scope but how can I destroy this scope in case someone navigates away from the form instead of finishing the usecase?

Comment: +1 since your suggestion for flash scope pointed me to the actual CDI-solution `@FlowScoped` as mentioned in my example.

Comment: @Aquillo, you can handle conversation scope management in a CDI bean-based JSF app with a [custom navigation handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15441777/1530938)