# Remove/destroy session scoped CDI managed bean

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, managed-bean, destroy, session-scope

I have a session scoped CDI managed bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped 
public class SampleBean implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

I need to remove this bean from the session after a certain flow for which I used the following code like as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485391/whats-the-convenient-way-to-destroy-sessionscoped/19486357#19486357):

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.getSessionMap().remove("sampleBean");
```

However, it does not work and the `SampleBean` remains in the session.
Am I missing something?

Comment: In theory, you can obtain access to a named CDI bean. Using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15394148/1530938), you can get the session bean and possibly set it to null

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In contrary to JSF managed beans, CDI managed beans are not stored directly by their managed bean name in the session map. They are instead stored in server's memory by the CDI manager implementation (Weld, OpenWebBeans, etc) using e.g. session ID as key.

The trick which you used there is therefore not applicable on CDI managed beans. You need to look for an alternate approach. The right approach in this particular case is to use `@ConversationScoped` instead of `@SessionScoped`. In properly designed web applications, there should never be the need to manually terminate a scope. So using `@SessionScoped` for a conversation/flow was already wrong in first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Inject
BeanManager beanManager;
.....
AlterableContext ctxSession = (AlterableContext) beanManager.getContext(SessionScoped.class);
for (Bean<?> bean : beanManager.getBeans(YourSessionBeanToBeDestroyedClass.class)) {
    Object instance = ctxSession.get(bean);
    if (instance != null)
        ctxSession.destroy(bean);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

And this ¿?

FacesContext
 .getCurrentInstance()
 .getApplication()
 .createValueBinding( "#{yourBeanName}").setValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null );

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean here?