# What's the convenient way to destroy @SessionScoped?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My problem is te data is not refresh in the datatable. I want to destroy the session scoped when I clicked to the item in the menu.I know that it's possible with Viewscoped but I want to learn other way.
Thank in advanced.

Controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyController implements Serializable {
 //getters and setters
...........
 }
```

Menu:

```
 <td><h:outputLink styleClass="itemOutputLink" value="#  {request.contextPath}/pages/page.faces">Page1</h:outputLink></td>`
```

Comment: Change your bean to `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: In other words you don't want it to be session-scoped at all.

Comment: really I want to keep the session scoped,I only  want to kill the session scoped from the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no really "clean" way of doing that. A `@SessionScoped` bean should live as long as a Session. Thus I emphasize again that you should better adjust the beans scope.

But if you really still need to do it, the easiest way would be to do it like this:

```
public static void removeSessionScopedBean(String beanName) 
{
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove(beanName);
}
```

For `@ViewScoped` beans you could do it this way:

```
public static void removeViewScopedBean(String beanName) 
{
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove(beanName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I have to use removeSessionScopedBean("MyController");

Comment: @user2683519 If it worked for you, please mark it as accepted. Then it won't be listed as unanswered anymore.